# How can I create .txt file from parallel JavaScript arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I currently have the following code, although poor, as I am unfamiliar with how to write to .txt files using JS.

Here are my parallel arrays:

```js
let myQuestions = ["Where is New York?", "Where is Paris?"]; 
let myAnswers = ["USA", "France"];
```

I would like the .txt file to look something like:

[image: txt file]

I believe that in order to achieve what I desire, I must loop through both arrays using a single for loop, as such:

```js
function addToTxtFile()
{
    for(let i = 0; i<myQuestions.length; i++){
        addToFile(myQuestions[i], myAnswers[i]); 
    }
}
```

Please note that the `addToFile` method does not exist, I am simply trying to map out the process.

Edit following answer:

HTML:

```html
<button type = 'button' onclick = 'addToTxtFile()'></button>
```

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const padString = (str) => str.padEnd(padding);
let content = `${padString('Questions:')} ${padString('Answers:')}\n\n`;


let myQuestions = ["Where is New York?", "Where is Paris?"]; 
let myAnswers = ["USA", "France"]; 

function addToTxtFile()
{
    for (let i = 0; i < myAnswers.length; i++) {
        let line = `${padString(myQuestions[i])} ${padString(myAnswers[i])}\n`;
        content += line;
    }
    
    fs.writeFileSync('out.txt', content, {encoding: 'utf-8'});

}
```

I am getting the following messages:
[image: error message]

And:

[image: error message]

Comment: A loop sounds like a reasonable process for this logic, yes.  As long as you know that the arrays "line up" with one another (same length, each index corresponds to the other's), then you can loop over both of them simultaneously and output the value from each.  But... What your actual question?  Where are you stuck?  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: require('fs') in browser wont work

Comment: Shall I do the quick fix then?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
let myQuestions = ["Where is New York?", "Where is Paris?"];
let myAnswers = ["USA", "France"];

const fileContent = getFileContent(myQuestions, myAnswers);
writeToFile(fileContent);

function getFileContent(questions, answers) {
    const padding = 30;
    const padString = (str) => str.padEnd(padding);

    let content = `${padString('Questions:')} ${padString('Answers:')}\n\n`;

    // assuming questions.length === answers.length
    for (let i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        let line = `${padString(questions[i])} ${padString(answers[i])}\n`;
        content += line;
    }
    return content;
}

function writeToFile(content) {
    // assuming NodeJS
    const fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFileSync('out.txt', content, {encoding: 'utf-8'});
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have updated my post with the code you provided, it doesn't seem to work. I ran `npm - v` in my terminal to make sure I had NodeJS and got the following output `8.5.0`, so I'm guessing my lack of NodeJS would not seem to be the problem.

Comment: @aleptian How is your setup? If you JS code executes on the browsers, then `fs` does not work. You can refer to the link mention in the comments section above. But you can still refer the above code for the string content that goes in the file.